# Xcode Override Storyboard Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, overriding

Quick question, I looked everywhere for an answer to no avail. I have a stroyboard that loads a tabViewController as the initial view. The first tab is autoselected and loaded (which is what I want). I have customized the layout of this view programatically. It has one UIImage and 6 UIButtons. I adjusted everything proprotionately in code. When the ViewController loads it does not apply my programatic formatting. If I leave the tab or select a button and then return to the ViewController the correct formatting **IS** there. I don't get why it doesn't load my programmed formatting to begin with. I have the formatting initialized in the viewDidLoad by calling a function However it still loads the storyboard layout. Please advise.

Thanky you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    [self orientationAdjust];
    NSLog(@"[INFO] %@ loaded",self);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(orientationAdjust:) name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object: nil];

}

-(void)orientationAdjust
{
    navHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    statusBarSize = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];


    screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(screen);
    screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
    screenCenter = CGRectGetMidX(screen);


    orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
    {
        halfScreen = screenHeight / 2;
        statusBarHeight = CGRectGetWidth(statusBarSize);

        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight + navHeight - 10, screenHeight, screenWidth / 3.5);
        bannerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(banner.frame);
        bannerWidth = CGRectGetWidth(banner.frame);
        btnKits.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenHeight / 2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight - 10, screenHeight / 2.5, screenWidth / 8);
        btnFusers.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenHeight / 2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + screenWidth / 8 - 10, screenHeight / 2.5, screenWidth / 8);
        btnKitId.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenHeight / 2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + screenWidth / 4 - 10, screenHeight / 2.5, screenWidth / 8);
        btnTips.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen , navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight - 10, screenHeight / 2.5, screenWidth / 8);
        btnResets.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen , navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + screenWidth / 8 - 10, screenHeight / 2.5, screenWidth / 8);
        btnExit.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen , navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + screenWidth / 4 - 10, screenHeight / 2.5, screenWidth / 8);
        [self setTextSize];



    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
    {

        statusBarHeight = CGRectGetHeight(statusBarSize);
        halfScreen = CGRectGetWidth(screen) / 2;
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, statusBarHeight + navHeight + 10, screenWidth, screenHeight / 8);
        bannerHeight = CGRectGetHeight(banner.frame);
        bannerWidth = CGRectGetWidth(banner.frame);
        CGFloat btnHeight = (screenHeight - tabBarHeight - bannerHeight) / 8;
        btnKits.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenWidth/2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + 10, screenWidth *.75, btnHeight);
        btnFusers.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenWidth/2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + btnHeight + 10, screenWidth *.75, btnHeight);
        btnKitId.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenWidth/2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight + (btnHeight * 2) + 10, screenWidth *.75, btnHeight);
        btnTips.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenWidth/2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight  + (btnHeight * 3) + 10, screenWidth *.75, btnHeight);
        btnResets.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen - (screenWidth/2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight +  (btnHeight * 4) + 10, screenWidth *.75, btnHeight);
        btnExit.frame = CGRectMake(halfScreen- (screenWidth/2.5), navHeight + statusBarHeight + bannerHeight +  (btnHeight * 5) + 10, screenWidth *.75, btnHeight);
        [self setTextSize];




    }



}
```

Comment: How are you formatting in the storyboard and in code? Are you using auto layout in IB?

Comment: autolayout is turned off on storyboard. I also have -(void)orientationAdjust:(NSNotification *)notification for the statusbarchange which applies the same code that is in orientationAdjust.

Comment: Just curious — why do you need this line called explicitly?

`[self supportedInterfaceOrientations];`

Comment: @Solomiya I don't I was using it while learning about orientations. While testing in the simulator I found that sometimes (NSUIntger)supportedInterfaceOrientations was not always being accessed so I was calling it right away. Now I have my app set to support all orientations. That is some code that needs to be cleaned up. Actually I have a lot of unused code laying around. :)

Comment: @user2506891 the point is, it is one of the system methods and that's not a good idea to call it explicitly. As far as I understand it may cause unpredictable issues since we can't be sure how exactly Apple uses those methods and what actually happens inside. I'd recommend to clean up your code from all the redundant code you said about and then try again :)

Comment: @Solomiya. Agreed. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the problem. When the compiler steps into orientationAdjust the value of orientation upon initial build is UIDeviceOrientationUnknown so I added

```
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown)
```

condition with the formatting I want. This loaded the view I needed.

Thanks to everyone for looking into this for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints to NO.

Comment: that didn't work. I applied this fix by entering self.btnName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; in viewDidLoad. is that correct?

Comment: Constraints for child elements are always added on the parent view of that child element. Try this self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO.